# Wait until the constructor finishes the initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I've below code to call api services in to my app.
The problem is when I call the `apiPost()` function the `this.apiToken` value is empty.
It happens because when I call `apiPost()` the constructor is not yet initialized and `apiToken` value is not yet assigned.

```
this.storageService.get(constant.storage_key.api_token).then((data) => {
      this.apiToken = data;
     //Is it possible to return Observable inside here?
});
```

How to wait until the `apiToken` is acquired before calling `this.httpAng.post()`?

```
export class MyApiService {

  apiToken = "";

  constructor(
    private httpAng: HttpClient,
    private storageService: StorageService,
  ) {
    this.storageService.get(constant.storage_key.api_token).then((data) => {
      this.apiToken = data;
    });
  }

 
  apiPost(aUrl, aParams): Observable<any> {
    let httpOptions: any = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.apiToken,
      }),
    }

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      // Post
      this.httpAng.post(aUrl, aParams, httpOptions).subscribe(
        async (data) => {
          switch (data['status']) {
            case 0:
              observer.next(data);
              break;
            default:
              this.alert.alertMessage(
                data['message']
                , () => {
                  observer.error(data)
                }
              )
              observer.error(data);
          }
        },
        async (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          observer.error(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Angular observable return undefined results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832863/angular-observable-return-undefined-results/61833059#61833059)

Changed my code according to the above post and used `from` from `rxjs` and `switchMap`.